# Representing date of a message at the top in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing chat application for Android. And I want to show date of messages at the top. For example if several messages have the same date, this date will be shown only near the first message. What is the sequence I should follow to solve this task?

Comment: post something you tries so far

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a very good open source library you will love it hopefully.

Usage: You need to clone this library either

- use this and take advantage.
- if you want to change the design and look go deep inside.

the thing you required is Use of messageList: 
[MessageList](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_MESSAGES_LIST.md)

[image]

Comment: they have lot more for you.